# kendoui grid from json

Tags: json, datagrid, kendo-ui

I'm getting an empty grid for this code:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
 <script>

$(document).ready(function () {

  var crudServiceBaseUrl = '/api/notes/';

  GridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
      read: crudServiceBaseUrl,
    },
  });

  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: GridDataSource.rows,
    navigatable: true,
    pageable: true,
    height: 300,
    toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
    columns: [
      { field: "id", title: "ID", width: 150 },
      { field: "name", title: "Book", width: 150 },
      { field: "author", title: "Author", width: 100 },
      { command: "destroy", title: "&nbsp;", width: 110 }
    ],
    editable: true
  });
});
 </script>
</div>
```

JSON goes like:

```
{"total": 6, "rows": [{"id": "AA", "name": "Foo", "author": "Bar"}, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can watch an examples of kendo ui grid usage at first [Grid - Binding to remote data](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/remote-data.html). At next you must read [kendo ui docs](http://docs.kendoui.com/).
For this example it need to define field for dataSource where data stored. Simply add a schema declaration after the transport... and extend transport parameters:

```
  GridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
      read: {
         url: crudServiceBaseUrl, 
         dataType: "json"
      }
    },
    schema:{
        data: "rows"
    }
  });
```